# How to test an ios8 app provisioned for the App Store?

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6

With ios7, I used to test the distribution app on my iPhone before submission.

Is there a way to run on my iPhone an ios8 app that has an App Store provisioning Profile ?

Comment: You should use [TestFlight](http://developer.apple.com/testflight) with internal testers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) to test your app with a maximum of 25 internal and 1000 external testers. You need to activate the possibility for your app in your itunesconnect. After that, your testers need to download the [TestFlight-App](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8) from the app store and then you have to invite them to test your app.

*note:* Before you can invited external testers your pre-release build must be reviewed by Apple.